# Finding nearest body of water (polygons) in the eight windrose directions from a point using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, nearest-neighbor, compass

I have a layer of points, and a layer of bodies of water (polygon). I am trying to find then nearest 8 bodies of water, in the 8 windrose directions (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW) within a given radius. If there are no bodies of water in that radius, then -1 will be used instead of the distance.

In the example image below, the set radius, `r`, is noted in red. Bodies of water are included in blue. In the example, the nearest bodies of water are found for N, E, SE, S, and NW. NE, SW, and W would return -1, since there is no body of water in that direction within radius r.

I have tried using the "Join Attributes by Nearest" tool, which will give me the k nearest bodies of water to each point. I figure I could manipulate the results from this tool to first discard any nearest neighbours farther away than radius, `r`, and then I could calculate the direction of each body of water from the point. However, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

[image: Example of bodies of water from the centre point of interest.]

Comment: You could create a new line layer from your point to all the directions you want with the lines being the length you want and then use 'join attributes by location' and select 'intersect' with the water bodies. It might be slightly easier but I'm not sure it would be more efficient.

Comment: @Walshe_d, thanks for the reply, is there a way you can suggest going about this?

Comment: @BERA I have never used it, but it looks open source... so I guess I could try. Do you have a suggestion of how to go about this in PostGIS?

Answer (score 3):

You can use QGIS expressions for this, see below for this and variants like calculating the length to the closest point on a lake shore within the maximum distance for each windrose direction.

*The final expression, used to label the points: one line for each windrose direction with 1= intersects a water body, -1 no intersection in the defined distance:*
[image]

#### 1. Get value which windrose direction crosses a water body within a maximum distance

1. Create the eight windrose directions as lines from the point:

   ```
    collect_geometries(
        array_foreach (
            generate_series (0,7),
            make_line (
                $geometry,
                project(
                    $geometry,
                    30000, -- change max. radius here
                    radians(360/8)*@element
                )
            )
        )
    )
   ```
2. Create a geometry collection with all water bodies that are in a maximum distance from the point:

   ```
    collect_geometries (
        overlay_nearest(
            'water', -- change layer name
            $geometry,
            max_distance:=30000,  -- change max. radius here
            limit:=-1
        )
    )
   ```
3. Use function `intersects()` to test whether the lines from step 1 interesct the geometry collection from step 2.
4. Stick the steps together and add the kind of output you wish: in my example, I create a label with the windrose directions an a number 1 if it intersects or -1 if it does not intersect:

   ```
    array_to_string (
        with_variable(
            'water',
            collect_geometries(
                overlay_nearest(
                    'sea',
                    $geometry,
                    max_distance:=30000,
                    limit:=-1
                )
            ),
            array_foreach (
                generate_series (0,7),
                array('N','NE','E','SE','S','SW','W','NW')[@element] || ': ' || 
                case
                when 
                intersects(
                        make_line (
                            $geometry,
                            project(
                                $geometry,
                                30000,
                                radians(360/8)*@element
                            )
                        ),
                        @water
                    )
                then 1
                else -1
                end
            )
        ), '\n' 
    )
   ```

#### 2. Get length along all windrose directions to the closest shore of a water body within maximum distance

For this, I have created an expression where you simply have to change a value on the second last line for the different windrose directions (returns `NULL` where no waterbody is inside the maximum distance) - see below.

*A variant of this expression used for visualization purpose: to create a dynamic label that lists the distances of the black solid lines from the center (red dot) to the closest shore (blue dot) along the windrose directions:*
[image]

```
-- Change the value on second last line to get the result for different windrose directions: 
--- 0 for N, 1 for NE, 2 for E, 3 for SE, 4 for S, 5 for SW, 6 for W, 7 for NW
length(
    array_foreach(
        generate_series (0,7),
        make_line (
            $geometry,
            closest_point(
            intersection(
                    make_line (
                        $geometry,
                        project(
                        $geometry,
                            30000,
                            radians(360/8)*@element
                        )
                    ),
                    collect_geometries(
                        overlay_nearest(
                            'sea',
                            $geometry,
                            max_distance:=30000, -- change distance here
                            limit:=-1
                         )
                    )
                ),
                $geometry
            )
        )
    )[0]  -- change value for windrose direction here
)
```

Comment: Interesting. But this approach produces a graphical result in the form of symology. What if we want to add a set of  attributes to each point feature with the distance to water in each of the directions?

Comment: @Llaves The initial question was unclear about what exactly the output should be. I added what you asked for at the bottom of the answer

Comment: Thanks for that expansion on the answer, but what I actually was suggesting was an answer that created a persistent result that is stored in fields in the feature layer. Since the Expression Builder seems to offer the same primitives as the Field Calculator, most of what you provided will work just fine. It's just a matter of deciding how to represent the 8 different directions - is it a list in the field, or eight fields. (I tried @Babel at the start but it won't take it for some reason)

Comment: OK, don't know what exacactly you tried and what went wrong... maybe worth aksing as a separate question, as here in the comment it's dificult to add all the necessary information.